# how to make a function reusable between two or more controllers in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I have a question as I am new to angularjs. I have searched alot but unable to understand the concept. I have a basic concept that there should be one controller for one view but we can have multiple controllers for a single view. I have below two controllers in a single view and there is one function let say for example addComma function which I have to use in both controllers but I want to write it one time to make it reusable between all controllers let say 5,6 controllers on the same view. So basically the question is how to make a function in a controller global between all controllers of same view or other views so that I can use it anywhere in my application. Appologies if it is a dumb question I am having a hard time understanding the concepts of angularjs.

```
 app.controller("GetChargesController", function ($scope, GetService, $rootScope) {
    $scope.Title = "Charges Details List";
    $rootScope.loading = true;
    // Calling Serivce Method here
    $scope.GetChargesDetails = GetService.GetAll("CommonApi", "GetChargesDetails").then(function (d) {
        $scope.ChargesDetails = d;
        $rootScope.loading = false;
    });
    // add comman function goes here
       $scope.addComma = function(x) {
        return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }

     });

    app.controller("GetPaymentsController", function ($scope, GetService, $rootScope) {
    $scope.Title = "Payments Details List";
    $rootScope.loading = true;
    // Calling Serivce Method here
    $scope.GetPaymentsDetails = GetService.GetAll("CommonApi", "GetPaymentsDetails").then(function (d) {
        $scope.PaymentsDetails = d;               
        $rootScope.loading = false;
    });
    // add comman function goes here
    $scope.addComma = function (x) {
        return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
       }

     });
```

Below is the generic service I've written to get any kind of data from database(using asp.net web api). As I've read that angular services can hold data and we don't need to call the database again and again when we are moving back and forth on links let's say for example I have these 3 links on a page. Home Link, PaymentCharges Link, Orders Link. so Home view will open by default. And when I click on PaymentCharges Link the call will go get data from database and render its view but when I click back on Home Link there should be no call going to database to get the data for the home page or when I click forward again on PaymentCharges Link the second time there should be no call going to database but what I see on firebug console option it is calling the function and going to database to get the data.I think we need to use cache to hold the data to not send the call to database.

```
    app.factory("GetService", function ($http) {
    var thisService = {};

    // get all data from database
    thisService.GetAll = function (controllername, methodName) {
        var promise = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/'+controllername + '/' + methodName
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            },
            function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        return promise;
    };
});
```

Comment: For this type of function you can create a custom filter I think it's appropriate to your problem.

Comment: @qchap has nothing to do with angular filters

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not agree with you. For a function like this `$scope.addComma = function (x) {
        return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
       }` I think a filter is a good option and you can have juste one implementation of this function. But I'm agree this proposition is just for the first part of the question.

Comment: @qchap ok...seem to be 2 very seperate issues here.My bad. Aamer try to keep questions focused to a single issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several ways to manage the service issue:

Re-use the promises by storing them in the service:

```
 // create an object to store promises
var promises = {};
thisService.GetAll = function(controllername, methodName) {

    promises[controllername] = promises[controllername] || {};
    // if the particular promise doesn't already exist create it as a property of above object
    if (!promises[controllername][methodName]) {
      promises[controllername][methodName] = $http({...}).then(...;

    }
    // now return the specific stored promise
    return promises[controllername][methodName];
 };
```

or store the data and use `$q` to return a different promise that resolves with the stored data when it already exists. Make sure to inject `$q` for this approach

```
var data = {};
thisService.GetAll = function(controllername, methodName) {

  data[controllername] = data[controllername] || {};

  if (data[controllername][methodName]) {
    // data exists for this controller and method, no need for new request
    return $q.resolve(data[controllername][methodName]);
  } else {
    return $http({...}).then(function(response) {
      // store the data for next use
      var newData = response.data;
      data[controllername][methodName] = newData;
      return newData;
    });    
  }   

};
```

Comment: What if we are getting data from database on the basis of some parameters like first time we send date parameter to get the current month data and next time we want to fetch previous 3 months data now in both cases we have to send call to database but if the parameter are same for both requests then fetch data from service. can we add a parameter check to above method to check if there is a change in the parameter then go to database otherwise return the same data stored in the service. I mean where to add this check in the service or in the controller?.

Comment: Could have another object that stores parameters and add some more conditional logic. Would only work for storing data only though not the promise concept. Also you would parobably want to merge the data instead of over writing it. There are also data storage libraries that you could investigate

Comment: All that sort of checking would be in service. Controller only passes the data back and forth between view and service and is not persistent through the life of the page the way service is

Comment: Thank You I've taken this answer for second part of my question and will implement this in this in my code. I have more questions but you guys have down voted me so I am unable to post new question on stack overflow. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Create an utils service and add the `addComma` function there. Inject the utils service and reuse the `addComma` in the controllers

```
app.factory('utils', function() {
  return {
    addComma: function() {}
  }
});

app.controller("GetChargesController", function ($scope, utils) {
  $scope.addComma = utils.addComma;
});

app.controller("GetPaymentsController", function ($scope, utils) {
  $scope.addComma = utils.addComma;
});
```

Comment: Thank You Gaara I've taken this answer for the first part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just store the data in the service?

You could do:

```
.then(function (resp) {
    thisService.controllerName.data = resp.data
}
```

Then you can reference the variable in your code using `GetService.controllerName.data`

Comment: won't work this way since the same `GetAll` makes numerous different  method name api endpoint calls also and I think you wanted `thisService[controllerName]data = resp.data` and `then()` needs to return the data also.

Comment: this was intended as psuedo code. the OP would of course have to adapt it to suit their needs. the general concept is still there. store it in the service.

Answer (score 0):

Instead I would suggest you to use something like this which might make it little more generic. Check the below code

1. appResources-Factory will contain all the resources that are needed to be exposed.
2. indexServices-Factory will contain all your services corresponding to your index controller.

   ```
   (function () {
   use strict';
   var commonServices = angular.module('commonServices', ['ngResource']);

   commonServices.factory('appResources', ['$resource',
      function ($resource) {

          var indexResource=$resource('/api/index/:id');
           return {

                  indexResource:indexResource

           }
   }]);

    commonServices.factory('indexService',['appResources',
    function (appResources){

       var getAllIndexes =function(sucesscallback){

          appResources.indexResource.query({}).$promise.then(
          //success
         function( value ){/*success events and Data is present in the 'value'*/
          sucesscallback(value);
          },
          //error
           function( error ){/*failure events*/}
          )

       }

      }
     ]);
   });
   ```
3. Controller Method calling the service and getting the value in $scope variables like

   ```
   (function () {
   'use strict';
    angular.module('saniehhaApp')
       .controller('indexController', indexController);
           indexController.$inject = ['$location', 'indexService'];
               function indexController($location, index,indexService) {
               /* jshint validthis:true */
                       indexService.getAllIndexes(function(sucesscallback){
                           $scope.value=sucesscallback;
                       })
                   //$locaton.qwets=....
                   }
   })();
   ```